# Factura XML en estándar UBL - Errores semánticos

Tags: php, xml, webservice

Estoy generando una Factura Electronica para la entidad tributaria DIAN en Colombia, pero me dice que tengo errores semanticos en la factura, ya agote todas las posibilidades, he revisado a detalle el XML y sus elementos, y no veo que existe ningun errata o faltante, de momento ya solo me queda preguntar por aqui haber si alguien le a sucedido lo mismo:

> Error en la línea (140): cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was
>   found starting with element 'cbc:ProfileExecutionID'. One of
>   '{"urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2":ID}'
>   is expected.

La carga la genero hacia el Webservice de pruebas (https://facturaelectronica.dian.gov.co/habilitacion/B2BIntegrationEngine/FacturaElectronica/facturaElectronica.wsdl), uso un Certificado de Pruebas y accesos de prueba validos.

Y el XML que mando es:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Invoice xmlns="http://www.dian.gov.co/contratos/facturaelectronica/v1" xmlns:cac="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2" xmlns:cbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2" xmlns:clm54217="urn:un:unece:uncefact:codelist:specification:54217:2001" xmlns:clm66411="urn:un:unece:uncefact:codelist:specification:66411:2001" xmlns:clmIANAMIMEMediaType="urn:un:unece:uncefact:codelist:specification:IANAMIMEMediaType:2003" xmlns:ext="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonExtensionComponents-2" xmlns:qdt="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:QualifiedDatatypes-2" xmlns:sts="http://www.dian.gov.co/contratos/facturaelectronica/v1/Structures" xmlns:udt="urn:un:unece:uncefact:data:specification:UnqualifiedDataTypesSchemaModule:2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xades="http://uri.etsi.org/01903/v1.3.2#" xmlns:xades141="http://uri.etsi.org/01903/v1.4.1#" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2 http://docs.oasis-open.org/ubl/os-UBL-2.1/xsd/maindoc/UBL-Invoice-2.1.xsd">
  <ext:UBLExtensions>
    <ext:UBLExtension>
      <ext:ExtensionContent>
        <sts:DianExtensions>
          <sts:InvoiceControl>
            <sts:InvoiceAuthorization>9000000124786152</sts:InvoiceAuthorization>
            <sts:AuthorizationPeriod>
              <cbc:StartDate>2018-10-29</cbc:StartDate>
              <cbc:EndDate>2020-12-31</cbc:EndDate>
            </sts:AuthorizationPeriod>
            <sts:AuthorizedInvoices>
              <sts:Prefix>PRUE</sts:Prefix>
              <sts:From>980000000</sts:From>
              <sts:To>985000000</sts:To>
            </sts:AuthorizedInvoices>
          </sts:InvoiceControl>
          <sts:InvoiceSource>
            <cbc:IdentificationCode listAgencyID="6" listAgencyName="United Nations Economic Commission for Europe" listSchemeURI="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:codelist:gc:CountryIdentificationCode-2.0">CO</cbc:IdentificationCode>
          </sts:InvoiceSource>
          <sts:SoftwareProvider>
            <sts:ProviderID schemeAgencyID="195" schemeAgencyName="CO, DIAN (Dirección de Impuestos y Aduanas Nacionales)">700200857</sts:ProviderID>
            <sts:SoftwareID schemeAgencyID="195" schemeAgencyName="CO, DIAN (Dirección de Impuestos y Aduanas Nacionales)">d80990f3-e5e5-41d0-a632-aa45298ed0da</sts:SoftwareID>
          </sts:SoftwareProvider>
          <sts:SoftwareSecurityCode schemeAgencyID="195" schemeAgencyName="CO, DIAN (Dirección de Impuestos y Aduanas Nacionales)">6d6582ba5cfc2b148cf2b4607b9e4b1966e07a4b4e9c3a707cfe354fb165b74a4f853595a95f8854f4e7731cd75043fa</sts:SoftwareSecurityCode>
        </sts:DianExtensions>
      </ext:ExtensionContent>
    </ext:UBLExtension>
    <ext:UBLExtension>
      <ext:ExtensionContent>
        <ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" Id="xmldsig-a3bf7689-a251-8584-2509-54da26046c5f">
          <ds:SignedInfo>
            <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"/>
            <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256"/>
            <ds:Reference Id="xmldsig-a3bf7689-a251-8584-2509-54da26046c5f" URI="">
              <ds:Transforms>
                <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/>
              </ds:Transforms>
              <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256"/>
              <ds:DigestValue>oQsBT4snpzP/xB2zT+iqA6lKMVbUgjd3hcyUJMTdTrA=</ds:DigestValue>
            </ds:Reference>
            <ds:Reference URI="#xmldsig-66507247-d3ff-7227-2e9e-48dd4a3fb534-keyinfo">
              <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256"/>
              <ds:DigestValue>ZovwLaIxJg/ezn50L3XtXWLYlTCMeKqBPiydw0kwx+4=</ds:DigestValue>
            </ds:Reference>
            <ds:Reference URI="#xmldsig-79b2dde6-d858-48a9-c825-d7f8d6fad906-object">
              <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256"/>
              <ds:DigestValue>ooyWjfK7JWdym+4kOE1JfZt3WYKPhNhTbmU/dq03XQU=</ds:DigestValue>
            </ds:Reference>
          </ds:SignedInfo>
          <ds:SignatureValue Id="xmldsig-a3bf7689-a251-8584-2509-54da26046c5f">RbN1TS7IuG/hB/FMCGONsKkkVioK/5HarZS1bIJj/AHJpXK8bNAN9IIwq+sbG8XpoqiqrqQEdHqwW8T+fap8BIr6WKSEl8h9yK90S112AQQHUDLIV261Gp3iNNRj4+3wYmhpdsdPFFnzzixKa0I0SsuQ25mqM+0HaIIk8Wj6TDC41Wdhu5Q1iWeEsWFEY0+LBhjpFXdZd66qHiq0nd/g6s4ZrRcrcKEsjzrSKe/kQzKI6ya4HXkiwsvZX/mokx+2Oa1/dGQzyVXJhQA1X5Ke66iV2cSdouRiK3v1pamGiwd3MSIvBU66+9Fmr5SNff9g3sHVwM4hnNYrLA0noIIHVw==</ds:SignatureValue>
          <ds:KeyInfo Id="xmldsig-66507247-d3ff-7227-2e9e-48dd4a3fb534-keyinfo">
            <ds:X509Data>
              <ds:X509Certificate>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</ds:X509Certificate>
            </ds:X509Data>
          </ds:KeyInfo>
          <ds:Object Id="xmldsig-79b2dde6-d858-48a9-c825-d7f8d6fad906-object">
            <xades:QualifyingProperties xmlns:xades="http://uri.etsi.org/01903/v1.3.2#" xmlns:xades141="http://uri.etsi.org/01903/v1.4.1#">
              <xades:SignedProperties>
                <xades:SignedSignatureProperties>
                  <xades:SigningTime>2019-02-25T18:16:17-05:00</xades:SigningTime>
                  <xades:SigningCertificate>
                    <xades:Cert>
                      <xades:CertDigest>
                        <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256"/>
                        <ds:DigestValue>X02jKw4C5nHlpr4FJE3Wl9KojJQSaoY+Y0QuBwRkjhk=</ds:DigestValue>
                      </xades:CertDigest>
                      <xades:IssuerSerial>
                        <ds:X509IssuerName>C=CO,L=Bogota D.C.,O=Andes SCD.,OU=Division de certificacion entidad final,CN=CA ANDES SCD S.A. Clase II,1.2.840.113549.1.9.1=#1614696e666f40616e6465737363642e636f6d2e636f</ds:X509IssuerName>
                        <ds:X509SerialNumber>9128602840918470673</ds:X509SerialNumber>
                      </xades:IssuerSerial>
                    </xades:Cert>
                  </xades:SigningCertificate>
                  <xades:SignaturePolicyIdentifier>
                    <xades:SignaturePolicyId>
                      <xades:SigPolicyId>
                        <xades:Identifier>https://facturaelectronica.dian.gov.co/politicadefirma/v2/politicadefirmav2.pdf</xades:Identifier>
                        <xades:Description>Política de firma para facturas electrónicas de la República de Colombia</xades:Description>
                      </xades:SigPolicyId>
                      <xades:SigPolicyHash>
                        <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256"/>
                        <ds:DigestValue>dMoMvtcG5aIzgYo0tIsSQeVJBDnUnfSOfBpxXrmor0Y=</ds:DigestValue>
                      </xades:SigPolicyHash>
                    </xades:SignaturePolicyId>
                  </xades:SignaturePolicyIdentifier>
                  <xades:SignerRole>
                    <xades:ClaimedRoles>
                      <xades:ClaimedRole>supplier</xades:ClaimedRole>
                    </xades:ClaimedRoles>
                  </xades:SignerRole>
                </xades:SignedSignatureProperties>
              </xades:SignedProperties>
            </xades:QualifyingProperties>
          </ds:Object>
        </ds:Signature>
      </ext:ExtensionContent>
    </ext:UBLExtension>
  </ext:UBLExtensions>
  <cbc:UBLVersionID>UBL 2.1</cbc:UBLVersionID>
  <cbc:CustomizationID>1</cbc:CustomizationID>
  <cbc:ProfileID>DIAN 2.1</cbc:ProfileID>
  <cbc:ProfileExecutionID>2</cbc:ProfileExecutionID>
  <cbc:ID>PRUE980000000</cbc:ID>
  <cbc:UUID schemeID="2" schemeName="SHA-256">bfe8bf2ec657a77e67f541ae82860f03d9beb9f5ae8f87d88b0498e44b7bc697</cbc:UUID>
  <cbc:IssueDate>2019-02-25</cbc:IssueDate>
  <cbc:IssueTime>18:16:17-05:00</cbc:IssueTime>
  <cbc:DueDate>2019-03-27</cbc:DueDate>
  <cbc:InvoiceTypeCode>01</cbc:InvoiceTypeCode>
  <cbc:Note>Factura emitida desde la plataforma https://www.moneybox.com.co</cbc:Note>
  <cbc:TaxPointDate>2019-02-25</cbc:TaxPointDate>
  <cbc:DocumentCurrencyCode>COP</cbc:DocumentCurrencyCode>
  <cbc:LineCountNumeric>1</cbc:LineCountNumeric>
  <cac:OrderReference>
    <cbc:ID>PO12345678</cbc:ID>
  </cac:OrderReference>
  <cac:AccountingSupplierParty>
    <cbc:AdditionalAccountID schemeAgencyID="195">1</cbc:AdditionalAccountID>
    <cac:Party>
      <cac:PartyName>
        <cbc:Name>Moneybox Colombia SAS</cbc:Name>
      </cac:PartyName>
      <cac:PhysicalLocation>
        <cac:Address>
          <cbc:ID>88780</cbc:ID>
          <cbc:CityName>Bogotá</cbc:CityName>
          <cbc:CountrySubentity>Cundinamarca</cbc:CountrySubentity>
          <cac:AddressLine>
            <cbc:Line>20 de noviembre 300</cbc:Line>
          </cac:AddressLine>
          <cac:Country>
            <cbc:IdentificationCode>CO</cbc:IdentificationCode>
          </cac:Country>
        </cac:Address>
      </cac:PhysicalLocation>
      <cac:PartyTaxScheme>
        <cbc:RegistrationName>Moneybox Colombia SAS</cbc:RegistrationName>
        <cbc:CompanyID schemeID="2" schemeName="31" schemeAgencyName="CO, DIAN (Dirección de Impuestos y Aduanas Nacionales)" schemeAgencyID="195">700200857</cbc:CompanyID>
        <cbc:TaxLevelCode listName="05">O-99</cbc:TaxLevelCode>
        <cac:RegistrationAddres>
          <cbc:CityName>Bogotá</cbc:CityName>
          <cbc:CountrySubentity>Colombia</cbc:CountrySubentity>
          <cbc:CountrySubentityCode>CO</cbc:CountrySubentityCode>
          <cac:AddressLine>
            <cbc:Line>20 de noviembre 300</cbc:Line>
          </cac:AddressLine>
          <cac:Country>
            <cbc:IdentificationCode>CO</cbc:IdentificationCode>
            <cbc:Name>Colombia</cbc:Name>
          </cac:Country>
        </cac:RegistrationAddres>
        <cac:TaxScheme>
          <cbc:ID>01</cbc:ID>
          <cbc:Name>IVA</cbc:Name>
        </cac:TaxScheme>
      </cac:PartyTaxScheme>
      <cac:PartyLegalEntity>
        <cbc:RegistrationName>Moneybox Colombia SAS</cbc:RegistrationName>
        <cbc:CompanyID schemeID="2" schemeName="31" schemeAgencyName="CO, DIAN (Dirección de Impuestos y Aduanas Nacionales)" schemeAgencyID="195">700200857</cbc:CompanyID>
      </cac:PartyLegalEntity>
      <cac:Contact>
        <cbc:Telephone>52 899 310 1442</cbc:Telephone>
        <cbc:ElectronicMail>contacto@sie-group.net</cbc:ElectronicMail>
      </cac:Contact>
    </cac:Party>
  </cac:AccountingSupplierParty>
  <cac:AccountingCustomerParty>
    <cbc:AdditionalAccountID>2</cbc:AdditionalAccountID>
    <cac:Party>
      <cac:PartyName>
        <cbc:Name>Publico en General</cbc:Name>
      </cac:PartyName>
      <cac:PhysicalLocation>
        <cac:Address>
          <cbc:ID>88700</cbc:ID>
          <cbc:CityName>Reynosa</cbc:CityName>
          <cbc:PostalZone>88700</cbc:PostalZone>
          <cac:AddressLine>
            <cbc:Line>20 de noviembre 300</cbc:Line>
          </cac:AddressLine>
          <cac:Country>
            <cbc:IdentificationCode>CO</cbc:IdentificationCode>
            <cbc:Name>Colombia</cbc:Name>
          </cac:Country>
        </cac:Address>
      </cac:PhysicalLocation>
      <cac:PartyTaxScheme>
        <cbc:RegistrationName>Publico en General</cbc:RegistrationName>
        <cbc:CompanyID schemeID="9" schemeName="31" schemeAgencyName="CO, DIAN (Dirección de Impuestos y Aduanas Nacionales)" schemeAgencyID="195">806000509</cbc:CompanyID>
        <cbc:TaxLevelCode listName="04">O-99</cbc:TaxLevelCode>
        <cac:TaxScheme>
          <cbc:ID>01</cbc:ID>
          <cbc:Name>IVA</cbc:Name>
        </cac:TaxScheme>
      </cac:PartyTaxScheme>
      <cac:Person>
        <cbc:FirstName>Publico</cbc:FirstName>
        <cbc:FamilyName>en General</cbc:FamilyName>
      </cac:Person>
      <cac:Contact>
        <cbc:Telephone>8999266046</cbc:Telephone>
        <cbc:ElectronicMail>contacto@sie-group.net</cbc:ElectronicMail>
      </cac:Contact>
    </cac:Party>
  </cac:AccountingCustomerParty>
  <cac:PaymentMeans>
    <cbc:ID>1</cbc:ID>
    <cbc:PaymentMeansCode>10</cbc:PaymentMeansCode>
  </cac:PaymentMeans>
  <cac:TaxTotal>
    <cbc:TaxAmount currencyID="COP">90000.00</cbc:TaxAmount>
    <cac:TaxSubtotal>
      <cbc:TaxableAmount currencyID="COP">1000000.00</cbc:TaxableAmount>
      <cbc:TaxAmount currencyID="COP">90000.00</cbc:TaxAmount>
      <cac:TaxCategory>
        <cbc:Percent>9.00</cbc:Percent>
        <cac:TaxScheme>
          <cbc:ID>01</cbc:ID>
          <cbc:Name>IVA</cbc:Name>
        </cac:TaxScheme>
      </cac:TaxCategory>
    </cac:TaxSubtotal>
  </cac:TaxTotal>
  <cac:TaxTotal>
    <cbc:TaxAmount currencyID="COP">0.00</cbc:TaxAmount>
    <cac:TaxSubtotal>
      <cbc:TaxableAmount currencyID="COP">0.00</cbc:TaxableAmount>
      <cbc:TaxAmount currencyID="COP">0.00</cbc:TaxAmount>
      <cac:TaxCategory>
        <cbc:Percent>0.00</cbc:Percent>
        <cac:TaxScheme>
          <cbc:ID>02</cbc:ID>
          <cbc:Name>INC</cbc:Name>
        </cac:TaxScheme>
      </cac:TaxCategory>
    </cac:TaxSubtotal>
  </cac:TaxTotal>
  <cac:TaxTotal>
    <cbc:TaxAmount currencyID="COP">0.00</cbc:TaxAmount>
    <cac:TaxSubtotal>
      <cbc:TaxableAmount currencyID="COP">0.00</cbc:TaxableAmount>
      <cbc:TaxAmount currencyID="COP">0.00</cbc:TaxAmount>
      <cac:TaxCategory>
        <cbc:Percent>0.00</cbc:Percent>
        <cac:TaxScheme>
          <cbc:ID>03</cbc:ID>
          <cbc:Name>ICA</cbc:Name>
        </cac:TaxScheme>
      </cac:TaxCategory>
    </cac:TaxSubtotal>
  </cac:TaxTotal>
  <cac:LegalMonetaryTotal>
    <cbc:LineExtensionAmount currencyID="COP">1000000.00</cbc:LineExtensionAmount>
    <cbc:FreeOfChargeIndicator>false</cbc:FreeOfChargeIndicator>
    <cbc:TaxExclusiveAmount currencyID="COP">90000.00</cbc:TaxExclusiveAmount>
    <cbc:ChargeTotalAmount currencyID="COP">1090000.00</cbc:ChargeTotalAmount>
    <cbc:PayableAmount currencyID="COP">1090000.00</cbc:PayableAmount>
  </cac:LegalMonetaryTotal>
  <cac:InvoiceLine>
    <cbc:ID>1</cbc:ID>
    <cbc:InvoicedQuantity>1</cbc:InvoicedQuantity>
    <cbc:LineExtensionAmount currencyID="COP">1000000.00</cbc:LineExtensionAmount>
    <cac:TaxTotal>
      <cbc:TaxAmount currencyID="COP">90000.00</cbc:TaxAmount>
      <cbc:TaxEvidenceIndicator>false</cbc:TaxEvidenceIndicator>
      <cac:TaxSubtotal>
        <cbc:TaxableAmount currencyID="COP">1000000.00</cbc:TaxableAmount>
        <cbc:TaxAmount currencyID="COP">90000.00</cbc:TaxAmount>
        <cac:TaxCategory>
          <cbc:Percent>9.00</cbc:Percent>
          <cac:TaxScheme>
            <cbc:ID>01</cbc:ID>
            <cbc:Name>IVA</cbc:Name>
          </cac:TaxScheme>
        </cac:TaxCategory>
      </cac:TaxSubtotal>
    </cac:TaxTotal>
    <cac:Item>
      <cbc:Description>auto</cbc:Description>
    </cac:Item>
    <cac:Price>
      <cbc:PriceAmount currencyID="COP">1000000.00</cbc:PriceAmount>
    </cac:Price>
  </cac:InvoiceLine>
</Invoice>
```

Comment: Pudiste encontrar el problema ? estoy en una situación similar

Comment: Hola @juan si te interesa podemos apoyarnos en el proceso, contactame al correo siegroupmx (a) gmail com

Comment: El XML tiene conceptos mezclados de Factura Electrónica v1 y factura electrónica con validación previa. Para la versión de factura electrónica con validación previa, buscar la caja de herramientas disponible en el portal de la DIAN (https://factura-electronica.dian.gov.co/)

Comment: @HugoMesíasCarrilloDíaz error mi estimado, no hay mixteo de conceptos, sino que se esta enviando al WS equivocado el XML.

Comment: Compañero, ¿Cual es el WS correcto? no es este ?
https://gtpa-webservices-input-test.azurewebsites.net/WcfDianCustomerServices.svc?wsdl

Comment: @CristianGomezRuiz ese es el WS del modo PILOTO, no te sirve para quedar Habilitado, debes usar el enlace que esta en el portal de la DIAN que dice "Habilitacion".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error no esta en el documento, ya que sus etiquetas están bien, esta adecuado para UBL 2.1, el error estaba en el WS al que se enviaba el XML, debe ser el WS nuevo asignado por Habilitación, vaya, ni en el **Kit de Herramientas** de la DIAN viene el WS Correcto, hay que obtenerlo al Registrar el Software.

A la fecha el portal de Habilitación y el Piloto, están inestables y la DIAN no puede proveer una plataforma funcional para **Factura con Validación Previa**.

La recomendación es continuar verificando el **Portal de Habilitación** hasta que se dignen a tener una versión estable que podamos utilizar para hacer el proceso de Habilitación, mientas solo queda esperar.